# Спрос на ИТ услуги

Tags: работа

Хочу получить какое-то представление об удовлетворенности спроса на ИТ услуги в разных Ит областях.  А точнее - найти наименее заполненную область, и направить туда свои усилия(в идеале).
Буду благодарен даже за пинок в сторону, где это можно поискать

Comment: Тут еще многое зависит от города в котором вы живёте, какие именно услуги выхотите оказывать? Разработка, например чего-либо, или же администрирование и т.д. Уточните свой вопрос, а то так сложно вообще понять что вас интересует.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я так полагаю, что смотреть спрос следует среди объявлений о вакантных местах, если хотите изучить ситуацию на данный момент. Если пытаться угадать на будущее время, то необходимо изучать нынешнюю ситуацию и пытаться предполагать, что будет актуально к тому моменту, как Вы станете достойным специалистом.
К примеру то, что может стать в центре внимания через несколько лет:
Уже который год идет активное развитие добычи "золотой" электронной валюты BitCoin и подобных.
Изучение робототехники, интеллектуальных (самостоятельных) домов.
Вероятно, через некоторое время, технологии Google Cars войдут в обширное применение.
Работа с "Облачными" системами хранения и обработки информации.
 Вероятно через некоторое время компьютерные технологии перейдут к передаче информации светом, вместо электричества. Как только подобие этих систем возникнет, лучше по быстрее влезть в них, что бы занять "теплое место". 
Интеграция мобильных устройств с облачной вычислительной мощностью.
И множество подобных примеров, из разряда "а может быть".